# NetLogo passing link breed as procedure parameter

Tags: netlogo

I am writing a utility procedure that identifies all the new `link-neighbors` of all the nodes in some turtle-set. I want to be able to use the same procedure for any link breed. The function will look something like this (not tested).

```
to-report all-neighbours [ NODESET EDGETYPE ]
  let nbr nobody 
  ask NODESET [ set nbr (turtle-set nbr EDGETYPE-neighbors) ]
  report nbr with [ not member? self NODESET ]
end
```

This will fail the syntax checker because EDGETYPE-neighbors is not a valid version of `breed-neighbors`. Is there a way to pass the link breed to a called procedure?

I think I can do a work around using the network extension with `nw:set-context NODESET EDGETYPE` and then `nw:turtles-in-radius 1` but would like a better way and may need to do the same general thing for link procedures that don't have nw versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all links with specified breed and use `[other-end]` to get the turtles:

```
to-report all-neighbours [ NODESET EDGETYPE ]
  let nbr nobody 
  ask NODESET [set nbr (turtle-set nbr [other-end] of (my-links with [breed = EDGETYPE]))]
  report nbr with [ not member? self NODESET ]
end
```

Usage (if your breed is e.g. relations/relation):

```
ask all-neighbours (turtle-set turtle 0) relations [show self]
```

Comment: I always forget that `breed` is a variable! Very elegant thanks